# Which option should I use if I want to learn theories that will account for as much English sentence's structure as possible

Tags: english, grammar, resource-request

Option 1: "Cambridge English Grammar Language" by Geoffrey Pullum 
or

Option 2: a site which, i think, is based on government and binding theory: https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/

if there are better options, please reccommend. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

By invoking "theory", you made the question very difficult to answer, because not only does the work have to account for English, it also has to be a theory. Which aspect is more important?

See p. 18 ff of the Cambridge grammar:

> The primary goal of this grammar is to describe the grammatical
>   principles of Present day English rather than to defend or illustrate a
>   theory of grammar.

Compare that to Santorini & Kroch ch. 1:

> This book is an introduction to generative grammar from a Chomskyan
>   perspective.

The Cambridge grammar is more a description of English with some assumed theoretical subcurrents, whereas Santorini & Kroch (or, Koeneman & Zeijlstra *Introducing syntax*) is an introduction to a syntactic theory, exemplified via English. If you are most interested in theory, Santorini & Kroch or, Koeneman & Zeijlstra would be better because that's what those books are about; whereas as a description of Modern English, the Cambridge grammar would be better.

Comment: Based on your's, I will pick the latter one.thanks a lot user6726.